# Converting String to Stream

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, windows-10-universal

So I am trying to serialize and deserialize an `IReadOnlyList<InkStroke>` from `Windows.UI.Input.Inking` for my UWP app, and I have used the following code to serialize the data:

```
var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
await canvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.SaveAsync(stream);
await stream.FlushAsync();

var buffer = new byte[stream.Size];
await stream.AsStream().ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
return Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
```

How can I deserialize this string to create an `IInputStream` (or `IRandomAccessStream` instead) which can be used in the `StrokeContainer.LoadAsync()` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following piece of code....

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(stringinput);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
IInputStream is=stream.AsRandomAccessStream(); //It will return an IInputStream object
```

Comment: You don't want `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` here - you want `Convert.FromBase64String`, given the way the string was created.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/save-and-load-ink):

```
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedString);
InMemoryRandomAccessStream inputStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
await inputStream.WriteAsync(data.AsBuffer());
inputStream.Seek(0);
await canvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.LoadAsync(inputStream);
```

Comment: The `AsBuffer` method is seemingly not available in UWP apps as it uses the `System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime` namespace.

Comment: You can add `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime` reference as [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime/). I tried it just now